# Why is my code stuck inside the for loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
        double [] tests = new double [5];
        
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 test results");
        for(int i = 0; i <= tests.length -1; a++){
            double grade = in.nextDouble();
            tests[i] = grade;
            sum = sum + grade;
            average = sum / 5;  
            if(tests[i] > average){
                a = a + 1;
            }else if(tests[i] < average) {
                b = b + 1;
            }else {
                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("The test results where " + Arrays.toString(tests));
        System.out.println("The average was " + average);
        System.out.println(a + " Students had above average scores");
        System.out.println(b + " Students had below average scores");
        System.out.println(c + " Students had average scores");
        
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm pretty new to java and I decided to mess around a bit. My question is why is my code stuck in what I'm guessing is inside the for-loop. The code runs but never finishes. I tried using a break inside the if statement and it worked but only for the first loop and that just ended the code.

Comment: I suggest adding `Syste.out.println()` statements to debug your code. You should print out the values of variables to see if they are what you think they should be. For more debugging tips, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your loop variable is `i`, but you're incrementing another variable, `a`, so `i` doesn't change.

Comment: "*`for(int i = 0; i <= tests.length -1; a++){`*" - Take look at the loop and start a debugger. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I think you're going to have to calculate the average of all the scores *before* you can determine whether any individual score is above or below that average.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing a instead of i.

Answer (score 1):

Becouse you are incrementing "a" variable. Just change "a" to "i".

```
import java.util.*;
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
        double [] tests = new double [5];
        
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 test results");
        for(int i = 0; i <= tests.length -1; i++){
            double grade = in.nextDouble();
            tests[i] = grade;
            sum = sum + grade;
            average = sum / 5;  
            if(tests[i] > average){
                a = a + 1;
            }else if(tests[i] < average) {
                b = b + 1;
            }else {
                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("The test results where " + Arrays.toString(tests));
        System.out.println("The average was " + average);
        System.out.println(a + " Students had above average scores");
        System.out.println(b + " Students had below average scores");
        System.out.println(c + " Students had average scores");
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to increment `i`, not `a`; otherwise, your code will cause `i` to stay at zero forever.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= tests.length -1; a++) // from
for(int i = 0; i <= tests.length -1; i++) // to
```